# Cant save vb6 application getting a System ... Unspecified Error

Tags: vb6

i am on vb6 app and it runs fine , but when i tend to save the application throwing an error:

```
System Error &H80004005(-2147467259). Unspecified Error
```

This application is consuming picturbox control and it is found that `.frx` file is deleting while saving the project.

Any help would appreciated . Thanks

Comment: My gut says that your Application Event Log is full. Clear it and try the build again.

Comment: still getting the error , i can compile ,build the exe but whenever tried to save after putting code it persist the issue

Comment: i think you can't delete the .frx file... it contain your form's picture , icon ...

Comment: yes , but .frx file is missing from directory when im saving the project and so i cant run the application . so i copy the .frx file from my back up and paste in the project directory and run the app smoothly except cant edit the code . please correct me if i am wrong .

Comment: How much free disk space do you have?

Comment: the free disk space is about 100Gb

Comment: Why would the presence if the .frx prevent you from editing code?

Comment: if .frx file is not present then project could not load an error will throw out

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still not clear.  You are missing your frx so that can cause a problem with that one form.  But you have a back up of it so why can't you use the backup copy?  Worst case scenario, you backup the offending form, delete the form from the project, and then recreate it.  Copy the code from the backed-up version.

Comment: as you said i recreated it , found that my application consuming shockwaveflash and culprit is shockwaveflash when it remove , i can edit the code and save so any advice ? UI part is designed by falsh

Answer (score 0):

Having googled the error this suggestions came up:

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=http://support.microsoft.com:80/support/kb/articles/Q236/2/86.asp&NoWebContent=1

http://www.datadynamics.com/forums/15296/PrintPost.aspx